# Anonymous JavaScript function not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I could really use a second pair of eyes on this. I get the following error:

**"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"**

Can anyone see what is wrong with this function because I can't seem to debug

```
    $(function(){
        $('#div-id').insertBefore('#sumbit-button');
    })();
```

Comment: remove the `()` at the end

Comment: I think you're confusing `$(function() {/*code*/});` and `(function() {/*code*/})();`

Comment: To extend the comment from @juvian, using jQuery's `$(function() {...})` syntax is a way to run a function when the DOM is available.  To us `(function() {...})()` is to run a function immediately.  Yours is just an uncomfortably hybrid of the two that doesn't mean anything (except the error you got!)

Answer (score 6):

jQuery already executes the function you pass to it, it does not return a function so you can't call it.

```
$(function(){
    $('#UGInterestedIn').insertBefore('#sumbit-button');
});
```

Comment: How would I modify this syntax then to execute this simple dom manipulation

Comment: As juvian said in another comment, remove the () from your original code. +1 to you aduch

Comment: Removing the parenthesis at the end didn't work. I get the same error

Comment: Then jQuery is probably not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 different things you can mean with this code. Either you're trying to make a function run on DOM ready, which would use the jQuery code:

```
    $(function(){
        $('#UGInterestedIn').insertBefore('#sumbit-button');
    });
```

Which is also what aduch said, but you can also be referring to a self-executing anonymous function, which would be this vanilla JS code:

```
    (function(){
        $('#UGInterestedIn').insertBefore('#sumbit-button');
    })();
```

The difference is that the first code requires jQuery to be included on the page, and loads the code when the DOM is ready. The second code runs the code immediately, but uses the anonymous function to change the scope of the variables. You're probably trying to do the first thing, but I thought I'd let you know about the second one too.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to do a simple dom manipulation but to be completely honest I rarely use JavaScript and I find it messy and hard to understand at times. I can usually accomplish what I need in this instance by managing the page life cycle on the back end of a .net app but this new project is all php